# Is there a way to pass the correct remote address to Nginx in a Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-network

I have a Nginx webserver that I'm running from inside a docker container. The problem I am having is that all client IP addresses in the nginx access.log are 172.19.0.1, the container's gateway. I would like the IP addresses shown to nginx to be the real IP addresses of the clients.

I've tried a few solutions that I found, including

1. Using Nginx's `realip` module

```
    set_real_ip_from 172.19.0.1;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive on;
```

which still logged the gateway ip

2. Setting the ports to `host` networking mode, which was ineffectual because I'm on macOS, and it is only supported on Linux.

The dockerfile I'm using looks like this

```
version: "3"
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - target: 80
              published: 80
            - target: 443
              published: 443
        volumes:
            # [my volumes]
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: nginx
```